# Serializing a dictionary with IConvertible values using Json.NET with the TypeNameHandling-flag

Tags: c#, json, json.net, iconvertible, jsonconvert

I have the following dictionary that I'd very much like to serialize using Json.Net. The dictionary contains items of the `IConvertible` interface allowing me to add whatever primitive type I need to the dictionary.

```
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, IConvertible>();
    dic.Add("bool2", false);
    dic.Add("int2", 235);
    dic.Add("string2", "hellohello");
```

I have the following implementation for serializing the list using Json.net:

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    var dicString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic,    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

This gives me the following output:

```
    {
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,         mscorlib],[System.IConvertible, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
      "bool2": false,
      "int2": 235,
      "string2": "hellohello"
    }
```

However. When trying to deserialize as such:

```
    var dic2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IConvertible>>(dicString);
```

... I get the following error:

```
    Error converting value False to type 'System.IConvertible'. Path 'bool2', line 3, position 16.
```

I've looked around and found the following; but setting the typeNameHandling didn't solve it. Nor can I decorate the `IConvertible` value with a type name attribute seeing as it is a dictionary.

[Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net)

I haven't found any other information on the topic so some help would be greatly appreciated!

I also found this solution but it involves creating a ExpandableObjectConverter which isn't a very elegant solution.

[Problems using JSON.NET with ExpandableObjectConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560085/problems-using-json-net-with-expandableobjectconverter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have several problems here:

1. You seem to have encountered an odd problem with Json.NET when deserializing to a target type of `IConvertible`.  When deserializing a convertible primitive type, it [calls](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L982) the system routine [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_System_IFormatProvider_) to convert the primitive to the target type (e.g. `long` to `int`).  And, for some reason, this system routine throws an exception when asked to convert a primitive to type `IConvertible`, even though that primitive is already of that type.
2. You are using [`TypeNameHandling.Objects`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) to serialize your dictionary of convertible values, however this setting is only documented to work work serializing to a JSON **object**.  Your values, however, will be serialized as JSON primitives, so the setting does not apply.

   To preserve type information for a dictionary of polymorphic primitives, you need to manually wrap the values in a container object, such as the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38340375/3744182) to *[Deserialize Dictionary<string, object> with enum values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38336390/3744182)*.  (That answer does not work here, however, because of problem #1.)
3. Unless you write a [custom serialization binder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm), `TypeNameHandling` is insecure and vulnerable to attack gadget injection attacks such as the ones shown in *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)* and *[External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49038055/3744182)*.
4. You are not using the same settings to deserialize as you are to serialize.

The above problems can be resolved with the use of the following [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
public class ConvertibleDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    [JsonDictionary(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
    class ConvertibleDictionaryDTO : Dictionary<string, ConvertibleWrapper>
    {
        public ConvertibleDictionaryDTO() : base() { }

        public ConvertibleDictionaryDTO(int count) : base(count) { }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDictionary<string, IConvertible>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dto = serializer.Deserialize<ConvertibleDictionaryDTO>(reader);
        if (dto == null)
            return null;
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, IConvertible>)(existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
        foreach (var pair in dto)
            dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ObjectValue);
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, IConvertible>)value;
        var dto = new ConvertibleDictionaryDTO(dictionary.Count);
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            dto.Add(pair.Key, ConvertibleWrapper.CreateWrapper(pair.Value));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dto);
    }
}

abstract class ConvertibleWrapper
{
    protected ConvertibleWrapper() { }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public abstract IConvertible ObjectValue { get; }

    public static ConvertibleWrapper CreateWrapper<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new ConvertibleWrapper<T>();
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new ConvertibleWrapper<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return (ConvertibleWrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConvertibleWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

sealed class ConvertibleWrapper<T> : ConvertibleWrapper where T : IConvertible
{
    public ConvertibleWrapper() : base() { }

    public ConvertibleWrapper(T value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override IConvertible ObjectValue { get { return Value; } }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then serialize and deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ConvertibleDictionaryConverter() },
};
var dicString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);

var dic2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IConvertible>>(dicString, settings);
```

Notes:

- Because [`[JsonDictionary(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) is applied to `ConvertibleDictionaryDTO` it is not necessary to enable `TypeNameHandling.Objects` globally.  This reduces your security risks.
- Constraining the type of object in `ConvertibleWrapper<T>` to implement `IConvertible` also substantially reduces security risks because attack gadgets are highly unlikely to implement `IConvertible`.
- However, for additional security you may still wish to write a custom serialization binder that allows only whitelisted known types.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7V2Lym).

Comment: Thanks for all the information and the working sample! Greatly appriciated.